# Issues with e.preventDefault in IE 7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

So I have a list of links in the top portion of my site that allow a user to click on them and when this click event happens I have a javascript function that scrolls a very large list of links within a div on the page. The problem is in IE7 and how it is handling the click event when it is fired. I am using jquery to prevent the default action and this works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE 8/9 but in IE7 the browser is trying to make use of the of the anchor in the default fashion. This anchor's href property is just a string that helps me identify the links in the lower portion of the page. If I click the link in IE7 I get a 404 but if I hit the back button and click the link again the script works correctly and the event is handled in the correct fashion. I also tried

```
event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
```

instead of e.preventDefault() but this makes no difference in how IE7 handles the click event in my scenario.

Any suggestions? Also, on my page I have a tabbed navigation that hides the data associated with that tab if the user is currently viewing the other tab (there are only 2 tabs). The content in either tab is roughly the same and the structure is exactly the same but when I execute the exact same process that is causing the error described above on the links in the first (default) tab, IE has no problems.

Comment: Please show us your full code.

Comment: Need to see the function that has click handler

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that IE7 has some issues with binding events to elements that are hidden on page. Or at least this is what I can make out of the issue that was occuring. Instead of using a .click event handler I have found a method provided by jQuery called .on() which has replaced the .live() method that has been deprecated since version 1.7.

> *"The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers."*

This seams to fix the problem in IE7.